# Pine script - How to identify price of the last bar

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm drawing support and resistance boxes in TradingView using pinescript. Currently all the boxes that I draw are just of one/same color. I want to mark all boxes above the current ask/bid price as Red and the ones that are below the current ask/bid price as Green. Any ideas?

These are the values for drawing the box currently.

```
boxLeft := bar_index-1
boxTop := open[1]
boxBottom := close[1]
boxRight := bar_index +25 // extending the box up to 25 candles from starting position

box.new(boxLeft, boxTop, boxRight, boxBottom, bgcolor=color.rgb(56,79,67,50), border_color=color.rgb(150,200,150,10))
```

I need to dynamically change the `bgcolor` based on the current ask/bid, and this should be applicable for all the drawings on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

you may try with the code below:

```
colorr = boxBottom > close ? color.green : boxTop < close ? color.red : color.blue

box.new(boxLeft, boxTop, boxRight, boxBottom, bgcolor=colorr, border_color=colorr)
```